# Draw QQ7 from 52 card deck... what is the conditional probability that after the last draw we get a full house?

Tags: probability

what is the probability of a full house given JJ7?

how would I start this?

I see 2 situations where it is a full house

option 1: 1 of the remaining 2 jacks + 1 of the remaining 3 sevens

option 2: 0 of the remaining 2 jacks + 2 of the remaining 3 sevens

my solution:

P = (1c2)*(1c3)+(2c3) / (49c2)

Comment: "is it basically just probability of a full house given JJ7?" Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you mixed up the upper and lower indices on the binomial coefficients, flaunted the operator precedence rules and didn't bother about the formatting, your result is correct: The probability to obtain a full house when uniformly randomly drawing $5$ cards without replacement from a standard deck, given that the first three cards drawn are a pair and a singlet, is

$$
\frac{\binom21\binom31+\binom32}{\binom{49}2}=\frac{6+3}{49\cdot24}=\frac3{392}\approx0.8\%\;.
$$